# Drupal 7 - Latest News block or view with thumbnails for the sidebar

Tags: drupal-7, view, feed

I'm developing a website with Drupal 7, and I need to manage a module for the latest news.
The "Latest contents" core module it's not enough for my needs.

So I have 2 questions:

1) Does exist a module that provides a block similar to the image I am attaching to this post? (thumbnail+article date+article title)

2) If it doesn't exist: How can I create a block to obtain my own latest news block? (may be I can modify some existing module?)

[image: The image is a mockup for what i need]

Help me with some hint, please...

Comment: I've submitted the issue also on drupal.org
 http://drupal.org/node/1945734

Does anyone have a suggestion for my problem?